# MySQL stored procedure - insert multiple rows

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures, rows

My application is logging the details of every http request in several MySQL tables via a stored procedure which is returning a unique request id to the application.

```
CALL http_req('ip', 'url', 'method', 'timestamp', @error, @request_id);
```

Now I also want to log all http request headers into a table, each header in a seperate row:

```
CREATE TABLE `http_header` (
`id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
`request_id` INT(10) UNSIGNED NOT NULL,
`name` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
`value` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL COLLATE 'utf8_unicode_ci',
PRIMARY KEY (`id`))
```

The problem is that each client has a different number and types of headers. I have not found a way to pass all header details to my stored procedure and then insert them into the above table.

Currently I have to generate and execute a second insert query from my application after the stored procedure call to save the headers:

```
INSERT INTO http_header (request_id, name, value)
    VALUES (20153, 'cache-control', 'max-age=0'),
           (20153, 'accept', 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8'),
           (20153, 'accept-encoding', 'gzip,deflate,sdch');
```

Is is possible save the second query and insert the headers from inside the stored procedure? Like passing all headers as a single string and parse it inside the stored procedure?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it is possible. MySQL does support sufficient flow control structures (`REPEAT`, `IF`) and string processing (`LOCATE()`, `SUBSTRING()`) to allow splitting the header strings in the database. Here is a very simplistic example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE http_req(IN ip CHAR(12), IN url VARCHAR(512), IN method CHAR(8), IN ts DATETIME, IN headers TEXT, OUT err INT, OUT request_id INT)
BEGIN
 DECLARE loc INT;
 DECLARE hloc INT;
 DECLARE hdr TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
 DECLARE hval TEXT DEFAULT NULL;
 DECLARE s TEXT DEFAULT NULL;

 START TRANSACTION;

 INSERT INTO http_requests VALUES (NULL,INET_ATON(ip), url, method, ts);
 SELECT last_insert_id() INTO request_id;

 REPEAT 
  SET loc=LOCATE("\n",headers);

  IF (loc = 0) THEN
   SET s=headers;
  ELSE
   SET s=SUBSTRING(headers,1,loc-1);
   SET headers=SUBSTRING(headers,loc+1);
  END IF;

  SET hloc=LOCATE(':',s);

  IF (hloc = 0) THEN
   SET hdr=s;
   SET hval='';
  ELSE
   SET hdr=SUBSTRING(s,1,hloc-1);
   SET hval=SUBSTRING(s,hloc+1);
  END IF;

  INSERT INTO http_header VALUES (null,request_id,hdr,hval);

 UNTIL (loc=0) END REPEAT;

 COMMIT;

END
```

There are some obvious problems with this code; like your headers will be stored incorrectly if they contain linefeed (`\n`). Also there is no error management (e.g. `err` return value is not populated correctly; no rollback). Fixing these has been left as an exercise to the reader ;)